# Splitting of square diagram in chain complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, abelian-categories, model-categories, causal-diagrams

Let us consider a square in chain complexes over a field $k$  \begin{array}{ccc}A & \xrightarrow{f} & B \\ \downarrow{g} & & \downarrow{h} \\ C & \xrightarrow{k} & D\end{array}

If A is chain equivalent to a direct sum of chain complexes $\bigoplus_i A_i$ such that each of the summands $A_i$ is concentrated in exactly one degree but any two of $A_i$ s are in different degrees, then is it true that the square is equivalent (in the diagram category) to a direct sum of the squares with top left corner is $A_i$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think so. Colimits in functor categories are computed objectwise, so we would need not only $A$ but also $B,C,D$ to be direct sums with the same indices and the morphisms would be restricted.

What I think your question is motivated by is the following. Consider the square
$$\tag{$\star$}\begin{array}{ccc}
\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I} A_i & \rightarrow &B\\
\downarrow && \downarrow\\
C &\rightarrow &D
\end{array}$$
By precomposition with the inclusion $A_j \hookrightarrow \bigoplus_i A_i$ we obtain a commutative square of the form
$$\tag{$\star(j)$}\begin{array}{ccc}
A_j& \rightarrow &B\\
\downarrow && \downarrow\\
C &\rightarrow &D
\end{array}$$
for every $j$.

Conversely, if we have a square of the form $\star(j)$ for every $j$, denote the top and left morphisms by $b_j: A_j \rightarrow B$ and $c_j:A_j \rightarrow C$ respectively. By the universal property of the direct sum, they determine unique morphisms $b:\bigoplus_i A_i \rightarrow B$ and $c: \bigoplus_i A_i \rightarrow C$. Moreover uniqueness of the universal property implies that these morphisms yield a commutative square of the form $\star$.

So there is a bijective correspondence between squares of the form $\star$ and a collection of squares of the form $\star(j)$, but it is not just *direct sums in the functor category*.

Comment: In general, of course we would not expect to have a direct sum of square.
However, if we assume the square is cofibrant, in the category of chain
complexes over a field,  I think we should be able to split the square into
a direct sum, since the images of the different A_i 's  are also a direct
sum